# In PHP how to retrieve document content of a mongoDB Document?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following script:

```
<?php

   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   // select a database
   $db = $m->myDB;
   $collection = $db->users;

   $cursor = $collection->find();

   //echo $cursor["Login"];

?>
```

And i want to display the value of "Login" from the collection "users", but what i tried (`echo $cursor["Login"]` doesn't work), any idea ?

p.s: i don't want to use foreach statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve records without any condition. So it is clear that whatever number of records present inside your collection `users` are going to get retrieved here. Now as you are using `find()` function, you can not directly get the value by `echo` as it is collection of object(records).

Here either you can use `foreach` loop to iterate & get the value of login from each record which you don't want right now or you can use `findOne()` with array inside having condition in associative manner to retrieve specific record.

Note: You can not directly echo the `$cursor`

Illustrating `findOne()`

Format : 
    `$cursor = $collection->findOne(array('key' => 'value'));`

You can have multiple conditions inside the array.

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne(array('login' => 'someemail@example.com'));
```

Or

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne(array('login' => 'someemail@example.com','password' => 'some_password'));
```

Note that findOne can give you single record that match the condition mentioned inside the array.

Comment: Can you illustrate findOne() with an example please ?

Answer (score 1):

try to `print_r($cursor)` and see what happens, may `$cursor` not array